# Sharepoint - Email enabled Document Library in 2007 or greater

Tags: email, document, library

We would like to forward documents to an email enabled document library.  Is there a way to get the data from the body of the email into this library?

Comment: yes you can have email of the body in the doc library and its open in the browser. The attached document is strored seprately. it is based on the setting you are going to do on the library.

Comment: Incoming email stores the whole email in a library as a document. Are you looking to store the contents of the mail into a separate column - that's not available in this feature.